# How to take a 3D point cloud of rotating object with a fixed kinect position using RGBDSLAM?

Tags: slam, navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have installed and used RGBDSLAM to take a 3D point cloud of my room.
I am using Ros groovy on Ubuntu 12.04 . I have an ASUS Xtion Pro live.

Now my question:-

In my project I will not be able to move my Asus .My Asus can direclty look at a pot. But I have to take a 3D point cloud of a rotating pot with a plant in it.
I can rotate the pot a full 360 degrees.
How do I achieve this using RGBDSLAM?

Rohit

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59295/how-to-take-a-3d-point-cloud-of-rotating-object-with-a-fixed-kinect-position-using-rgbdslam?/) by [Rohitdewani](https://answers.ros.org/users/4133/rohitdewani/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-03-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Most easily by putting it in front of a featureless background, e.g. a black bedsheet. Make sure that the turntable is the same color, otherwise you have prominent feature at the edge between sheet and turntable.

Or you can program a node that filters the images from the xtion pro, e.g. by color or depth, to remove the background. Then subscribe rgbdslam to the filtered image.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2013-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rohitdewani](https://answers.ros.org/users/4133/rohitdewani/) on 2013-03-27**:
That is a great idea.I cannot use the black cloth but May be I was thinking if I could make the changes in the RGBDSLAM source code it self to filter the images.
Can you please tell me which file I should look into?
Or may be if your could just guide me a little to write this node?

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2013-03-29**:
Depends on how you want to filter the image (I don't know how exactly you would do that, depends on your scene). I'd look into the node (.cpp/.h) class. Maybe write a new method to filter the feature_... attributes which contain the info about features.